# History of $\sin(nx) = 2^{n-1} \prod_{0}^{n-1} \sin\left(x + \frac{\pi k}{n}\right)$

Tags: mathematics

What is the name of this identity? Who discovered this identity? What is the history behind this? I have looked up on Wikipedia with little  documentation of the identity

see finite product of trigfunctions here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Multiple-angle_formulae

Cross post : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3692240/history-of-sinnx-2n-1-prod-0n-1-sin-leftx-frac-pi-kn-rig?noredirect=1#comment7587656_3692240
tl;dr: looking for the history behind this identity

Comment: HI, cross-posting is not recommended.  The mods will migrate a post to a different group when deemed appropriate.

Comment: It's expressing $sin(\omega\tau)$ as the product of phase-shifted $sin(\tau + \phi_n)$ , which suggests some sort of transform function from frequency to phase space.  But that's just a guess

Comment: François Viète and Chebyshev come to [mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Sine,_cosine,_and_tangent_of_multiple_angles).